# Github desltop - How to setup an external editor to a specific repo?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I'm using Github Desktop. There is an option to select favourite external editor, but it applies to all my repositories. Is there any ability to select only for specific repo?

#### For example

1. Repo `A` with **android project**
2. Repo `B` as **php project**

So I'd like to set **Android Studio** as an external editor for repo `A` and **PhpStorm** for repo `B`. Is it possible?

Comment: Why can't you just do it the other way around? I.e. Set up the repo from your IDE?

Comment: Hm, I don't really know about that. Could u please explain that?

Comment: Tools like Sublime Text, IntelliJ Idea, etc all allow for direct Git integration via either keys(SSH) or username and password (HTTPS). Use a search engine to find more. Also, your question is not completely clear, do you want to open a repository as either android or PHP on the same IDE or have different IDEs for each kind of project? If the first option is what you're looking for, you just need to make sure your IDE supports both and that's done via plugins, sometimes pre-installed, You can try by creating an Android and a PHP project on your IDE of choice.

Comment: As a side note, I wouldn't recommend checking in project configuration files into your git repository unless you're completely certain (which means you're consciously restricting) as each developer has their own approach. I would commit only the source code.